# django how to display number of items

Tags: django

I was wondering how I do count the number of poll in my question model using set_count 
and I also want to display it in a template please show me using the code thanks

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


    def __str__(self):

        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):

        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    site_url = models.URLField()

    website_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    budget = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    duration = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    description = models.TextField()
```

I want the show the total of question

Comment: Please share the models thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you write in your **views.py**:

First, to count it, you have to import the model itself

If **models.py** and **views.py** both belong to same app:

```
from .models import Question
```

If they belong to different apps:

```
from <appname>.models import Question
```

I'll assume they belong to the same app, in **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question

def index(request):
    number_of_questions = Question.objects.count()
    context = {
        'number_of_questions':number_of_questions,
    }
    return render(request, '<appname>/index.hmtl>', context)
```

On the first line of the function it just counts the number of questions with `.count()` method which comes with django. On the second line we define context that we want to use in template, in this case `'number_of_questions':number_of_questions`, so in the html template to display this number we'll use `{{ number_of_question }}`, have we defined it like so: `'questions':number_of_questions`, then in the template we would use `{{ questions }}`, the end result will be that it shows `number_of_questions`.

In **index.html** (Or whatever you named the template):

```
<p>number of questions:</p>
    <p>{{ number_of_questions }}
```

If you have trouble understanding anything I suggest you read through these:

[Django documentation on templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#syntax)

[Some information about python dictionaries](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

**EDIT**:

I also highly recommend reading this:

[Django documentation about making queries to the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/)